# How to send data from WKWebview to HTML file using evaluateJavaScript | iOS | Objective-C

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I need to pass certain values to my HTML from WKWebview.

Here is my code snipped of what I've tried yet.

```
 [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.getElementById('popo_data').innerHTML = feed,OMG,BTC;" completionHandler:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
         if(error != nil) {
             NSLog(@"######## SomeFunction Error: %@",error);
             return;
         }

         NSLog(@"########  SomeFunction Success");
     }];
```

Answer (score 1):

That does not look like well formed JavaScript, because quotes are missing around the string you're assigning to the `#popo_data` element. I suppose you're getting a syntax error here.

Try the following:
`document.getElementById('popo_data').innerHTML = "feed,OMG,BTC"`

If this does not work, you can debug your webview with Safari by connecting the debugger to your device or simulator. Safari Preferences > check "Show Develop menu in menu bar."

Comment: WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById('popo_data').innerHTML = 'feed,OMG,BTC' '),

Getting this error when trying your code.

Comment: Then this is likely that at time of evaluation, there is not HTML element with `id="popo_data"` present in the web document.